# Start peak2peak at certain value

Tags: matlab

If you have the next values:

1. 30
2. 24
3. 21
4. 26
5. 23
6. 19
7. 17
8. 11
9. 6
10. 10

How is it possible to do a peak2peak starting from 4 (thus value 26) untill the last value? So in this case the answer should be 20.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What do you mean by a peak2peak? You have to explain your background and problem a lot more. Most people are not familiar with your problem and would not know what this means other than guessing. Please read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use only the values starting from 4th value of your vector:

```
a = [30,24,21,26,23,19,17,11,6,10];
peak2peak(a(4:end))
```